# Occasional segmentation fault on malloc'd pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc, fault

I have the following code, in which whenever I try to free my malloc'ed memory I sometimes get a segmentation fault. This fault only occurs when freeing memory associated with some of my struct members (only on the nickname and beyond), meaning I never get a segmentation fault for `free(player->name)`, but about half the time I get segmentation faults from the other two frees (seeing how instruments is a null, it has no effect)

```
typedef struct player_t {
    char * name;
    char * nickname;
    Instrument * instruments;
    int instrumentAmount;
} * Player;

Player playerCreate(const char* name, const char* nickname,
int maxInstruments) {
    Player one=malloc(sizeof(Player));
    if(one==NULL || !checkLegalName(name)|| !checkLegalName(nickname) ||   maxInstruments<=0) {
        return NULL;
    }

    one->name=malloc(strlen(name)+1);
    one->nickname=malloc(strlen(name)+1);

    if(!one->name || !one->nickname) {
        playerDestroy(one);
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy(one->name,name);
    strcpy(one->nickname,nickname);
    one->instrumentAmount=maxInstruments;
    one->instruments=NULL;
    return one;
}
```

followed by this:

```
void playerDestroy(Player player) {
    if( !player) {
        return;
    }

    free(player->name);
    free(player->nickname); // this is where it happens.
    free(player->instruments);
    free(player);
}
```

Any help in solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: Most probably you are going out of boundaries of some array, writing over some address and get the error when you are freeing. You should try debugging and probably even more convenient running `valgrind` to see what's going wrong and where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (main-)problem is in this line:

```
Player one=malloc(sizeof(Player));
```

Player is defined as a pointer to the player_t struct and so you are not reserving enough memory to keep the whole structure. It is only enough for the first pointer (`name`) which is why you see the crash when accessing `nickname`.

Try:

```
Player one=malloc(sizeof(struct player_t));
```

Comment: This is why many people don't like pointer types hidden inside a typedef and use the idiom `toto *x = malloc(sizeof *x)` to allocate the space.

Answer (score 1):

```
one->nickname=malloc(strlen(name)+1);
...
strcpy(one->nickname,nickname);
```

What if `nickname` is longer than `name`?

Comment: Thanks for noticing, fixed it :)